# Having trouble with setting a div to be readable by a screenreader

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

Problem: I have a div that is nested inside a span tag with the role of button, whenever the span button is focused, what I want to have happen is the screen reader 'read' the text in the nested div --> p tag when the span receives focus

```
<span role="button" tabindex = 0>
    <div id= "nestedDiv" aria-hidden ="false" tabindex = 0>
           <p tabindex =0> Read this text </p>
     </div>
</span>
```

I tried different screenreaders and different browsers, same issue, it doesn't read the div, it just skips over to the next readable element.

Comment: What's the purpose of using a span as a button? Is the user meant to take an action? If so then an anchor, button or input might be a better semantic choice that'll let the user take that action.

Comment: "I have a div that is nested inside a span tag" — OK, so you don't have HTML. That's a problem.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this in NVDA + firefox and it reads "read this text. button" when I tab to the span.  Which browser are you having trouble in?
You could try adding an ID to the paragraph such as `<p id="foo">` and add `aria-labelledby="foo"` to the `<span>`.
However:
Karl Brown's comment is 100% accurate - it's best to use semantic markup. Does the span do something? If so, it should be a button. Does it bring you to a different page? If so, it should be an anchor.
Also, why so much tabindex? It takes three tabs to get outside of this element, which is not good. If you use proper semantics you wont need tabindex and you wont need any aria attributes.

Comment: thank you, I'm learning 508 compliance on the run, so forgive the novice insight into the subject matter. The codebase is already defined so I'm learning how to inject Accessibility standards on the go.

Comment: Sometimes you're stuck with crappy code and it's great to try to make it more accessible! I would recommend having `tabindex=0` on the `<span role="button">` element only. When I tested it with NVDA/Firefox it identified it as a button and read the text within the paragraph. If you find it's not working on other screenreaders, the aria-labelledby approach might be ideal, but it's still best to remove the extra tabindex attributes as it's currently not accessible. It's generally best to not use tabindex or aria attributes unless you need to.

Comment: thank you! That's my reality but getting insight from people familiar with Accessibility is always appreciated, especially because it's a very scarce group compared to preference of many developers investing their time in the 'fun' sides of coding aka frameworks.